# bundle update FileOverflow - file too large

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I don't have a lot of experience building gems (the workflow, etc).

Anyway, when I try to reinstall a local gem, I get this error:

```
Gem::Package::TarWriter::FileOverflow: You tried to feed more data than fits in the file.
```

This is after I uninstall the gem, repackage it with gem build and update it with bundler.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what this error means? I'm assuming the gem is too large. Currently, it's 148K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you may be including the gem on itself in the files list?

Check this [issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/623) and the code that will provide a better error text is still not released as it will in rubygems >= 2.2